# ERROR Accessing SQL Server .. How to publish MVC Application in IIS

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-7, iis-6

**publishing MVC Application in IIS**.Here i am using **Model First approch so connection string is automatically created** and my sql server name is .\SQL EXPRESS (not local) and uses **Windows authentication to login the SQl Server 2008**. and **Visual Studio 2015** is used

check this error :**The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'SP_Login', database 'Hospital_Employee', schema 'dbo'** Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException:

Web.Config

```
    <configuration>
      <configSections>
        <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
        <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
      </configSections>
      <appSettings>

        <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
        <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
        <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
        <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
      </appSettings>
      <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6" />
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6" />

        <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="100" />
        <authentication mode="Forms">
          <forms loginUrl="~/Login/Login" />
        </authentication>
        <roleManager enabled="true" />
      </system.web>
      <connectionStrings>

      <add name="Hospital_EmployeeEntities" **connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Hosp_Employee.csdl|res://*/Models.Hosp_Employee.ssdl|res://*/Models.Hosp_Employee.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=Hospital_Employee;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />**
        </connectionStrings>
      <entityFramework>
        <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
        <providers>
          <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices,

 EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Kindly help me to configure Sql Server 2008 with IIS

Answer (score 0):

Add a new user to your database and use `User ID=YourUserName;Password=YourPassword;` instead of `integrated security=True;`

or you can add a new user:  `IIS APPOOL\DefaultAppPool` (or whichever AppPool you're using) to your database. (then you can use `integrated security=True;`)

To add a user in SQL Server, follow this:

- Go to Databases -> Security -> Logins
- Right click logins and select "New Login"
  In the Login name field, type IIS APPPOOL\YourAppPoolName (don't click search)
- Alternatively click on SQL Server authentication and provide YourUserName and YourPassword
- Click OK

Comment: As per @Davor Dumeljic : i had changed to mixed type authentication.

Comment: **@CoOL** : Since  i am using **DefaultAppPool** under **Default Web Site** and my application name is DemoMVCApp (is this ok) ?                                                                                                            so my login name should be    **IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool** ?                  then i need to give somepassword and click ok ?                                                           kindly check whether i am doing write thing ?

Comment: You do not need to give any password to add `IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool` user. Just enter the login name, select Windows authentication and click OK.

Comment: **@CoOl : ERROR** Create failed for Login 'IIS APPOOL\DefaultAppPool'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

Comment: **@CoOl : ERROR Details**Program Location:

   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.CreateImpl()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Login.Create()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.CreateLoginData.LoginPrototype.ApplyGeneralChanges(Server server)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.CreateLogin.DoPreProcessExecution(RunType runType, ExecutionMode& executionResult)
   at

Comment: may be because your 'IIS APPOOL\DefaultAppPool' has a typo in APPOOL (as it only has 2 P's but needs 3)?

Comment: **@CoOl** dude this ERROR is fixed **"Create failed for Login 'IIS APPOOL\DefaultAppPool'. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)" ** changed to :IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool

Comment: what I mean is if it errors while adding a new user to SQL Server, then you might be entering wrong login name. It has to be `IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool` rather than `IIS APPOOL\DefaultAppPool`

Comment: **@CoOl** , i can't access SQL Server 2008.    Kindly check my SQL Server 2008 Version                                                   Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio     10.0.1600.22 
Microsoft .NET Framework    2.0.50727.8662                       and  i am using  DefaultAppPool  4.0                                                                                                                                 any version problem or any other isse . i guess i am missing some thing

Comment: and  this is connection string :<connectionStrings>

      <add name="Hospital_EmployeeEntities" **connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Hosp_Employee.csdl|res://*/Models.Hosp_Employee.ssdl|res://*/Models.Hosp_Employee.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=Hospital_Employee;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />**
        </connectionStrings>

Comment: Not sure what you mean by can't access SQL Server 2008. All you need to do is `go to SSMS` (Sql Server Management Studio), select your `SQL Instance (.)`, expand `Security` Folder, right click on `Logins -> New Login`, enter `IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool` and click OK

Comment: yes , i had done this but when i  tried to login from my web app i can't access Sql Database. so i had made some changes in **IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool** properties Under  **User Mapping**  i had mapped database ** "Hospital_Employee"** to  **IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool**  ,but still i cant Access DB from Hosted web app, is there any debug method to get exact error ?

Comment: try to set `<customErrors mode="Off"/>` in your `web.config` inside `<system.web>`

Comment: check this error :**The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'SP_Login', database 'Hospital_Employee', schema 'dbo'**                        Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException:

Comment: In your `SSMS` go to `Logins`, and select `DefaultAppPool` user, go to `User Mappings` and select your database, then in the box below check `db_owner` role as well.

Comment: **ERROR: "Failed to generate a user instance of SQL Server due to a failure in impersonating the client. The connection will be closed."**                                                                                              Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

 Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'SP_Login', database 'Hospital_Employee', schema 'dbo'.

Comment: under User Mapping i had mapped database ** "Hospital_Employee"** to **IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool**     but i don't mentioned  **Default Schema** and checked  **db_owner**  but **public is already checked**

Comment: try assigning `dbo` to default schema

Comment: can't do that which will not be saved in SQL Server(Some error window shown)

Comment: ERROR: "Failed to generate a user instance of SQL Server due to a failure in impersonating the client. The connection will be closed."

Comment: SQLExpress database file auto-creation error: 

The connection string specifies a local Sql Server Express instance using a database location within the application's App_Data directory. The provider attempted to automatically create the application services database because the provider determined that the database does not exist. The following configuration requirements are necessary to successfully check for existence of the application services database and automatically create the application services database:

Answer (score 0):

you should first enable both authentification types Windows & sql server users (most people make here first mistake)

Then create user like @CoOl told you

And on the end add connection string into your web.config file

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConString" connectionString="Data Source=_____;Initial Catalog=____;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=_____;Password=______" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: @ Davor Dumeljic : i can't access SQL Server 2008. Kindly check my SQL Server 2008 Version Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 10.0.1600.22 Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0.50727.8662 and i am using DefaultAppPool 4.0 any version problem or any other isse . i guess i am missing some thing –

Answer (score 0):

**Issue Fixed : Things to do**

**we can add a new user in SQL Server 2008 Database (Here Hospital_Employee DB):  and new user is *IIS APPOOL\DefaultAppPool* (or whichever AppPool you're using in IIS Manager for this web app ,here i used DefaultAppPool) . (then in your Connection string in Web.Config file you can use *integrated security=True*;)**

**To configure follow these steps **

a, Expand your database (Here : Hospital_Employee) in Sql Server.
then expand Security in "Hospital_Employee DB"  and
expand Users in Security and
**Add new user specify name as

IIS APPOOL\DefaultAppPool (or whichever AppPool you're using).                           then click ok**

b, right click DB "Hospital_Employee DB"
then **click Properties then select Permissions

 then** **CHECK the "Execute"** property.
c, Refresh the DB

then Run the Hosted Web Application then try Login.
now it will access the DB and works fine